# Webpack code-splitting from within vendor files?

Tags: webpack, momentjs, lodash, vue-cli, code-splitting

We're using a handful of js libraries, which internally import both lodash and moment.

Both are known for being able to bloat your bundles very easily unless your smart with your imports.

The we're trying to reduce our initial bundle sizes as both lodash and moment are only needed in maybe 20% of the site.

--

I know in our code base we can do things such as

```
const moment = () => import(/* webpackChunkName "moment" */'moment');
```

However as the libraries which are deep inside the `node_modules` are just doing:

```
import moment from 'moment'
import _ from 'lodash'
```

Is there anyway using webpack that we can mark all of these as they should be split out?

Maybe useful to know were using the Vue CLI to build the project so our webpack config is actually stored inside `vue.config.js`

Answer (score 0):

webpack [`splitchunks.cacheGroups`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/#splitchunkscachegroupscachegrouptest) is what you need. Check the link.

Basically you get to hand pick which module goes into which chunk:

```
optimization: {
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        lodashAndMoment: {
          test(module, chunks) {
            //...
            // WATCH OUT! WATCH OUT! WATCH OUT!
            // I'm not 100% sure `module.name` actually looks like this
            // It's my IRRESPONSIBLE GUESS just to show the idea.
            return module.name === 'lodash' || module.name === 'moment';
          }
// ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, not interested in the `vue.config.js` part, you figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue – not on a Vue project but maybe it helps a bit – on our companies website which I have rewritten completely. What I have done is:

1. set `concatenateModules` to `true` (https://webpack.js.org/plugins/module-concatenation-plugin/)
2. set `namedModules` and `namedChunks` to `true` (we need this because many of the plugins I wrote use webpack too and I didn't want to load jQuery etc. 10 times)
3. set `runtimeChunk` to `'single'` and just load it once before all other files (!) (this handles all webpack compiled scripts)
4. set `usedExports` to `true` to skip exports that has been used before
5. add `cacheGroups` as hackape suggested
6. add a plugin like `BundleAnalyzerPlugin` to see which files are really bloating the project
7. add the `TerserPlugin` to minify/comprimise everything (will be used as default in webpack 5)
8. do this: `const function = require('lib/source/function')` instead of `const { function } = require('lib')` (this will just require this little script and not the hole lib)

and if you want use a manifest plugin to make a better use of hashed file names

Here is our config: https://gist.github.com/muuvmuuv/b97153fcfe462d837ef8e8535f69fc82